# Absolutely new to Python. Issue with extracting integers from a textfile

Tags: python

I've just started learning python and am having a really hard time with some stuff. I have a textfile that has one source, like a reference in a scientific paper. I need to write a script that checks if the dates in this file are between 1900 and 2012. If so, it needs to list the dates vertically in a list.

If the source has the two dates 1934 and 1968 then it would be printed:

```
1934
1968
```

So far I have

```
f=open('filename.txt')
words=f.readlines()
year=range(1900,2013)
```

I have tried a variety of subsequent lines but never get anywhere. Example:

```
for year in words:
    print year
```

I'm not sure at all on how to proceed. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: You don't want a range, you just want to know whether the int value of the current word is bigger than or equal to the floor, and lower than or equal to the ceiling.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are three things you need to do to make your code work. The first is to search your text file for digit characters using a simple regular expression and the `re` module. Then you need to convert each string you find to an integer. Finally, you can compare it with your boundary numbers:

```
import re

with open("filename.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()                     # read the whole file

for match in re.finditer(r"\d+", text): # find all strings of consecutive digits
    num = int(match.group())            # convert to integer
    if 1900 <= num <= 2013:             # test boundaries
        print num
```

Comment: If the file has non-integer words, a ValueError will be raised.

Comment: The file does have non-integers - it contains a reference to a scientific paper.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I received an error when I entered in the 'for' line. I'm assuming that my top two lines are still present above your first 'with' statement? (  f=open('filename.txt') <br>
words=f.readlines()  )

Comment: Also, `split()` won't work. It fails on input like "(Gamma et al. 1980)"

Comment: Oh, I see, the input text is not just the numbers. I think a simple regex is probably the best way to extract all numbers from arbitrary text. I'll edit.

Comment: Thank you, Blckknght, and thanks for the the #'s. The issue I have now is that I receive a 'invalid syntax' error when I enter in the 'for' statement still, with an arrow under the 'r' in 'for'. Do you have any idea why this would be? nvm: had to double enter :P Let me check the rest of it now.

Comment: Victory! Cheers, guys :) I can no progress. If it's not too much trouble, could I ask for an explanation relating to the 're.finditer(r"\d+", text)' phrase? I'm not entirely sure about the terms in the parentheses.

Comment: A syntax error pointing at `for` probably indicates that you have something wrong on the previous line, such as unclosed parentheses. `re.finditer` is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer), and the pattern `r"\d+"` means "match any sequence of one or more digits" (the leading `r` makes it a "raw" string, so I don't need to worry about Python misinterpreting the backslash).